# Dynamically create new fields to submit multiple row entries into the table model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial _form that contains multiple fields for creating a recipe. I'm currently able to add a *single* entry for *cooking step* and the *cooking step* attaches itself with the recipe_id upon submission.

Problem:

Obviously each recipe has **MORE** than just 1 cooking step. How do I dynamically add another/or more fields below it to create Step 2, Step 3, Step 4, and etc. All of these steps go into a model **cooking_step.rb**. I've seen the railscast video on nested forms and not only is it a bit confusing, I don't think it applies to what I'm doing since I'm working with the **SAME MODEL** as opposed to MULTIPLE MODELS.

Code:

Below is what I have so far in my controller:

```
def create 
    @cookingstep = CookingStep.new(params[:cooking_step])
    @cookingstep.recipe_id = @recipe.id
    @cookingstep.save 
end
```

Below is what I have so far in my partial _form.html.erb:

```
<%= fields_for @cookingstep do |din| %>
    <%= din.label :instruction %>
    <%= din.text_field :instruction %>
<% end %>

<%= submit_tag "Submit"  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler design would be to have the steps 1, 2, 3, etc in a list format, with a blank space at the bottom for a new entry. In the list, provide options for edit, delete, and change position in sequence. When you have that working you may want to give it some ajax. Then the best ajax treatment for a recipe would be to make them draggable to change sequence, in_place_editing for in place editing, and a delete button next to each for deleting that specific step. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

You should start from the Recipe model, which has many cooking steps, and there you go, you have multiple models as explained in the [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) videos.

Comment: I did try that railscast video before but couldn't figure out the following:

module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end

Can you please explain which items in the code need to be replaced after copy and pasting it from railscast.

Comment: Sorry for mixing the code and my question, but my question was is there anything I need to change in the module ApplicationHelper to make it work for my code?